# conversion of typedef int to java.Actually I want to convert a .h file in c to java

Tags: java

how to represent typedef int (*hashtable_hash_function)(void *key, int size)
in java code.
Actually I want to convert a .h file in c to java

Comment: "*Actually I want to convert a .h file in c to java*" - I approve, you may proceed.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ironic!

Comment: user2523918 - Do you want to rewrite a C object in Java, access a C component in Java or something else? What have you attempted thus far. Did it work? If not how much closer to the goal did it get you?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at JNA and [JNAErator](https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) especially.

Comment: His question shows no effort and no research that has been done. We shouldn't encourage questions like that by answering it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I generally agree, and I did upvote your comment. :-) But I don't think it hurts to point people in the right direction. I didn't post a complete solution, and it's not like using JNAerator requires no effort by itself.